# Why some object methods are invisible in a console log

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, leaflet, console.log, angular-leaflet-directive

I am using a plugin to integrate leaflet into an AngularJS project. As I wanted to check if the API was the same as the standard leaflet, I logged into the Chrome console the leaflet object provided by dependency injection; several methods were missing.

Surprisingly enough, when I tried to call those methods on that object anyway, they did work.

How can this be ? What makes some properties visible or not in the console ?

Comment: Check the prototype.

Comment: I did check the prototype which was empty. What I didnt check was __proto__ which actually contains the method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the

```
__proto__
```

property of the object

I had checked .prototype but not this one